# Replicating Linux production environment locally on Mac

Tags: php, centos, mac-osx, lamp

I have a remote CentOS server and i want to recreate, as close to possible, this environment locally on a Mac currently acting as a fileserver to our office to provide a development environment that matches the production and staging environment as closely as is possible. The app is hardcoded in many places to expect directory paths to work as per our CentOS environment - namely `/home/USER/public_html/...` for each account. PHP is setup to run on our remote servers as DSO with a few additional modules such as mod_deflate running. Is there any reason why this can't be duplicated locally on a Mac in an environment that is close enough to our staging environment to make this workable. Other considerations are the fact i would need a method of dynamically mapping www.remotedomain.com to its local equivalent (maybe by doing something like prefixing with dev. like  dev.remotedomain.com or suffixing with .local)

Answer (score 3):

Just install a virtualization software like VMWare Fusion, Virtualbox (which is free) or Parallels, then run CentOS from inside a VM. You can't come closer.

Comment: i should have pointed out that i may need to share this environment, it could even be put together on another Mac that we currently use as a fileserver

Comment: Well, if you can put a VM on the server, you can still share this any way you like.